# Merge the results of table in R

Tags: r

I want to count occurrences of the three factors for each column of mydata, so I thought of the function table

Some data of mydata:

```
              A0AUT     A0AYT     A0AZT     A0B2T     A0B3T
100130426 no_change no_change no_change no_change no_change
100133144 no_change no_change      down no_change no_change
100134869 no_change no_change no_change no_change no_change
10357     no_change        up no_change no_change        up
10431     no_change        up no_change no_change no_change
136542    no_change        up no_change no_change no_change
> str(mydata)
'data.frame':   20531 obs. of  518 variables:
 $ A0AUT: Factor w/ 3 levels "down","no_change",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ A0AYT: Factor w/ 3 levels "down","no_change",..: 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ A0AZT: Factor w/ 3 levels "down","no_change",..: 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ A0B2T: Factor w/ 3 levels "down","no_change",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ A0B3T: Factor w/ 3 levels "down","no_change",..: 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ A0B5T: Factor w/ 3 levels "down","no_change",..: 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ A0B7T: Factor w/ 3 levels "down","no_change",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ A0B8T: Factor w/ 3 levels "down","no_change",..: 2 1 1 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ A0BAT: Factor w/ 3 levels "down","no_change",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ A0BCT: Factor w/ 3 levels "down","no_change",..: 2 2 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Now I do:

```
occurences <- apply(mydata, 1, table)
> occurences[[1]] # 100130426

no_change        up 
      508        10 
> occurences[[2]] # 100133144

     down no_change        up 
       45       446        27
```

But I want them as a matrix (or at least I think it is easier to deal with) so I made this:

```
  freq <- sapply(occurences, function(x){
    c(x, rep(0, 3 - length(x)))
  })

> freq[,1:5]
          100130426 100133144 100134869 10357 10431
no_change       508        45        14     3     3
up               10       446       411   330   268
                  0        27        93   185   247
```

However as you can see the number of no_change for 100133144 went to the up row!

My expected output would be:

```
> freq[,1:5]
              100130426 100133144 100134869 10357 10431
    up               10        45        14     3     3
    no_change       508       446       411   330   268
    down              0        27        93   185   247
```

How can I make it so that each value is well placed?
As you can see each table may be just one to three elements, so doing:

```
freq <- matrix(unlist(occurences), nrow=3)
```

results on error, because not multiple of 3.

I might have taken a bad approach to count the frequencies of mydata by column. I would prefer to have an approach with just base R, without using any library

Comment: [Please make your question reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: `library(reshape2); dcast(melt(mydf, id="id"), value ~ id)`

Comment: Can you show the `str(mydata)`.

Comment: Your expected output may be based on the original dataset.  I meant based on the part of the data you showed.

Comment: @akrun I have included it, is just reordering the first column, or anyone which don't have all the three factors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do with `table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'matrix' and reshape from 'wide' to 'long' (using `melt` from `reshape2`), and call `table` on the concerned columns to get the frequency count.

```
library(reshape2)
table(melt(as.matrix(mydata))[c(3,1)])
#              Var1
#value       10357 10431 136542 100130426 100133144 100134869
#  down          0     0      0         0         1         0
#  no_change     3     4      4         5         4         5
#  up            2     1      1         0         0         0
```

---

Or using only `base R`, we can just `unlist` the data to get a `vector`, replicate the 'row names' (using `col`) and then call the `table`

```
table(unlist(mydata), row.names(mydata)[col(mydata)])
#             Var1
#value       10357 10431 136542 100130426 100133144 100134869
#  down          0     0      0         0         1         0
#  no_change     3     4      4         5         4         5
#  up            2     1      1         0         0         0
```

---

Another option is `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
add_rownames(mydata) %>%
    gather(Var, Val,-rowname) %>% 
    group_by(rowname, Val) %>%
    summarise(n=n()) %>% 
    spread(rowname, n, fill=0)
```

#### Update

If the dataset columns are `factor`, we can convert it to `character` class before doing the `unlist`

```
mydata[] <- lapply(mydata, as.character)
```

#### Update2

If this is based on each row

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(mydata))))
#          100130426 100133144 100134869 10357 10431 136542
#no_change         5         4         5     3     4      4
#down              0         1         0     0     0      0
#up                0         0         0     2     1      1
```

---

Or using only `base R`, we create a vector of unique elements in the dataset ('nm1' - here it is already known, but if it is not,  `nm1 <- unique(unlist(lapply(mydata, as.character)))`), then loop over the rows using `apply` with `MARGIN=1`, use `tabulate` after converting the row vector to `factor` with `levels` specified as 'nm1'.  In `tabulate`, we can also specify the length of return vector i.e. length of 'nm1'.  The output will be a `matrix`.  We can assign the row names (`row.names<-`) as 'nm1'.

```
nm1 <- c('up', 'no_change', 'down')
`row.names<-`(apply(mydata, 1, function(x)
     tabulate(factor(x, levels=nm1),length(nm1))), nm1)
#          100130426 100133144 100134869 10357 10431 136542
#up                0         0         0     2     1      1
#no_change         5         4         5     3     4      4
#down              0         1         0     0     0      0
```

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(list(A0AUT = c("no_change", "no_change", 
"no_change", 
"no_change", "no_change", "no_change"), A0AYT = c("no_change", 
"no_change", "no_change", "up", "up", "up"), A0AZT = c("no_change", 
"down", "no_change", "no_change", "no_change", "no_change"), 
    A0B2T = c("no_change", "no_change", "no_change", "no_change", 
    "no_change", "no_change"), A0B3T = c("no_change", "no_change", 
    "no_change", "up", "no_change", "no_change")),
 .Names = c("A0AUT", 
"A0AYT", "A0AZT", "A0B2T", "A0B3T"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("100130426", 
"100133144", "100134869", "10357", "10431", "136542"))
```

Comment: I would prefer a solution without calling any other library, but good solution anyway

Comment: `Error in col(occurences) : 
  a matrix-like object is required as argument to 'col'`, not working :( but thanks, (I think the data I posted is the same as I used) but I don't really understand the second argument.

Comment: @Llopis I posted the data used.  It is a `data.frame`.  The second argument is actually replicating the row names of mydata to make the lengths equal.  If your dataset is `matrix` or `data.frame`, `col(mydata)` gives you the column index.

Comment: Oh, sorry I first tried with the `occurence` object! it works with the data.frame of course

Comment: @Llopis  BTW, if your object is a `list`, you would get the same error.  But, based on the data showed, I assumed that it either data.frame or matrix.  For example, `lst <- rep(list(1:3), 4); col(lst)
#Error in col(lst) : a matrix-like object is required as argument to 'col'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103379/discussion-between-llopis-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2):

Promoting my comment to an answer:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(mydf, id="id"), value + variable ~ id, length)
```

This supposes that the numbers are an id-variable. If they are stored as rownumbers:

```
dcast(melt(as.matrix(mydf)), value ~ Var1)
```

Both give:

```
      value 10357 10431 136542 100130426 100133144 100134869
1      down     0     0      0         0         1         0
2 no_change     3     4      4         5         4         5
3        up     2     1      1         0         0         0
```