# One large frequency table for multiple variables

Tags: r, count, frequency-analysis

I have a dataframe with 4 nominal variables with 3 levels each (A, B, C). I want to make a frequency table of height 4 and width 3, where each row contains the count of the levels for that variable.

```
df <- data.frame(var1=c('B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
                 var2=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
                 var3=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C'),
                 var4=c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'))

head(df,10)
    var1 var2 var3 var4
1    B    A    A    A
2    A    A    A    A
3    C    A    A    A
4    A    A    A    A
5    B    B    B    B
6    B    B    B    B
7    C    C    C    B
```

The result should be something like this:

```
      A B C
var1  2 3 2
var2  4 2 1
var3  4 2 1 
var4  4 3 0
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35381409/16647496), we can combine outputs from the `table` command, `t`ranspose it, and make it as a data frame with `row.names` coming from the column names of `df`.

```r
as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(unlist(df), row.names(df)[col(df)])), 
                     row.names = colnames(df))

     A B C
var1 2 3 2
var2 4 2 1
var3 4 2 1
var4 4 3 0
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! I would never have come up with that myself... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

With `stack`:

```r
t(table(stack(df)))

      values
ind    A B C
  var1 2 3 2
  var2 4 2 1
  var3 4 2 1
  var4 4 3 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `tidyverse` package, which is great at data manipulations like these:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("var"),
               names_to = "col",
               values_to = "val") %>% 
  mutate(count = 1) %>% 
  group_by(col) %>% 
  summarise(A = sum(count[val == "A"]),
            B = sum(count[val == "B"]),
            C = sum(count[val == "C"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "value", values_from = "value", 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0, names_sort = TRUE)

  name A B C
1 var1 2 3 2
2 var2 4 2 1
3 var3 4 2 1
4 var4 4 3 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tabyl`

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df, everything()) %>% 
  tabyl(name, value)
```

-output

```
 name A B C
 var1 2 3 2
 var2 4 2 1
 var3 4 2 1
 var4 4 3 0
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `xtabs` with `stack`:

```
xtabs(~ind+values, data=stack(df))

      values
ind    A B C
  var1 2 3 2
  var2 4 2 1
  var3 4 2 1
  var4 4 3 0
```